# Can we retrieve historical database growth report for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Can someone share a method on how can I retrieve the database growth report from the date of creation till current for MySQL? Coming from Oracle background, I understand for Oracle we can do a script to query the creation date or from the snapshot. But I don't now if MySQL has a similar table/view which I can query and check from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot obtain the info about DB size in the past - server do not store those information.

You can obtain the info about current DB size. It can be obtained from the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/files-table.html) system pseudotable. You can shedule the get of this info in some table using [CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html), so You will see the dynamic of size change.

But I think (especially assuming You use InnoDB engine with file_per_table enabled) the best way is to obtain DB size info directly from the OS' filesystem (and shedule it using OS' sheduler - cron or another). Of course, You can store that info in MYSQL server table :) - it's not a problem to add it via command-line client.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes I'm able to retrieve the current sizes from information_schema as well. I did google around and found most solution is based on what you mention which is to schedule a cron to check the growth size from current time & couldn't find anything about getting historical DB growth. Well thanks for the clarification, I'll try to schedule the cronjob to monitor the DB growth.

Comment: @JasonOon If You'll monitor the DB growth getting data from the information_schema use MySQL' inner sheduler, not OS' one. But when You'll get data from the filesystem then use cronjob. To get data from information_schema and shedule it with cron is a poor idea I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have one query, which works on SQL Server however not sure whether it would work in MySQL, you may need to modify a bit. Below query would give you statistics over last one year.

```
     DECLARE @startDate DATETIME;SET @startDate = GETDATE();
SELECT PVT.DatabaseName ,
PVT.[0] ,
PVT.[-1] ,
PVT.[-2] ,
PVT.[-3] ,
PVT.[-4] ,
PVT.[-5] ,
PVT.[-6] ,
PVT.[-7] ,
PVT.[-8] ,
PVT.[-9] ,
PVT.[-10] ,
PVT.[-11] ,
PVT.[-12]
FROM (
SELECT BS.database_name AS DatabaseName ,
DATEDIFF(mm, @startDate, BS.backup_start_date) AS MonthsAgo ,
CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 1), AVG(BF.file_size / 1048576.0)) AS
AvgSizeMB
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset AS BS
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupfile AS BF
ON BS.backup_set_id = BF.backup_set_id
WHERE NOT BS.database_name IN ( 'master', 'msdb', 'model', 'tempdb' )
AND BF.[file_type] = 'D'
AND BS.type = 'D'
AND BS.backup_start_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @startDate) AND
@startDate
GROUP BY BS.database_name ,
DATEDIFF(mm, @startDate, BS.backup_start_date)
) AS BCKSTAT PIVOT ( SUM(BCKSTAT.AvgSizeMB) FOR BCKSTAT.MonthsAgo IN ( [0] ,
[-1], [-2], [-3], [-4], [-5], [-6], [-7], [-8], [-9], [-10], [-11], [-12] ) )
AS PVT
ORDER BY PVT.DatabaseName;
```

Comment: There is no backupset/backupfile or something similar to them in MySQL.